# AVX2 instruction interrupt in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, sse, avx, avx2

Here's the c++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char a[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        a[i] = 1;

    for (int i = 32; i < 64; i++)
        a[i] = 0;

    __m256i x = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i *)(a));
    __m256i y = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i *)(a + 32));

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        cout << (int)x.m256i_i8[i];
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        cout << (int)y.m256i_i8[i];
    cout << endl;

    __m256i z = _mm256_xor_si256(x, y);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        cout << (int)z.m256i_i8[i];
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code in VS2013, the **xor** operation will interrupt.

And I think my cpu can support AVX2 since x and y can be output successfully.

Can somebody tell me how to fix this, please?

Comment: Nope, your processor doesn't have AVX2. 256-bit integer load already existed in AVX. The 256-bit integer xor is AVX2.

Comment: It's easy to check: `static bool AVX2(void) { return CPU_Rep.f_7_EBX_[5]; }` ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh.aspx))

Comment: Do I need to include a lib for using "CUP_Rep"? @Drop

Comment: So is there any quick way to do 256-bit bitwise operation for machine just supporting AVX? @Mysticial

Comment: Yes, but it is unlikely to be faster than using 128-bit. Don't bother with 256-bit integers unless you have AVX2.

Comment: Actually here's the problem I need to solve, there are two bit-vectors, and I want to do the "AND" operation.

Comment: Can I use the 256-bit float to do this? Is there any precision problem? @Mysticial

Comment: Yes you can. But 128-bit integer logic has 3x the throughput of the 256-bit floating-point ones. So the 128-bit integer will be about 50% faster assuming both cases saturate the execution units.